# How to upper case every first letter of word in a string, meanwhile removing eventual whitespaces in Java?

Tags: java, uppercase, lowercase

How to upper case every first letter of word in a string, meanwhile removing eventual whitespaces in Java?

```
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name.replaceAll("\\s+","")
        .substring(0, 1)
        .toUpperCase() + name.substring(1)
        .toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly, I would like to do it as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "this is a Sample text";
        String[] tokens = input.split("\\s+");
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : tokens) {
            output.append(s.trim().replaceFirst(String.valueOf(s.charAt(0)),
                    String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)))));
        }

        System.out.println(output.toString());//ThisIsASampleText
    }
```

**Note:** I didn't consider usual special characters separating words like `,`,`.`,`;` etc. If you need these stuffs along with space please add them in the regex while splitting into words.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with any effort, use a library like Guava.

See documentation of `CaseFormat` here: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#caseformat